agora_token_builder module not found
I want user agora_token_builder in my django project  I have install it many times
but on importing it show module not found  but in local machine all thing working corectly but at the time hosting the application
error shown
ModuleNotFoundError at /
No module named 'agora_token_builder'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://pratyush6653.pythonanywhere.com/
Django Version: 4.0.6
Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError
Exception Value:
No module named 'agora_token_builder'
Exception Location: /home/Pratyush6653/video_call/base/views.py, line 2, in 
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.10.5
from agora_token_builder import RtcTokenBuilder in my views.py file
please give the solution it means alot for me

Tips to help you fix this issue, ModuleNotFoundError on your hosting environment, PythonAnywhere.

Ensure that in your local development environment, that your agora-token-builder is part of the package before deployment. If not, please install it by running these commands below.

pip install agora-token-builder

  # freeze the package to requirements.txt file
    pip freeze > requirements.txt


Then push it to your GitHub again or your code hosting environment to proceed.

Use a virtual environment if you aren’t already. This helps to isolate your project’s dependencies and makes sure that the correct versions are used. Activate your virtual environment and install the requirements.

  pip install -r requirements.txt



You can install it on the PythonAnywhere console if the above methods fail with this -> pip install agora-token-builder .

Check for typos or mismatches of what you are trying to import in your view prior to importing them. Goodluck



I am glad to hear that, kindly tick my answer correct so that it will help other developers that find the same challenge/issue as you have when they search for this title of your question. @PratyushChauhan
